# I add FloatLayout widgets in a loop, but only the last one has a background

Tags: python, kivy

I created my own widget class and assigned a default background to it, in the python file, several are created in the loop, but the background image is only visible on the last one created, why is this happening? Here is the code:

Here is the working (incorrect) code I got from my application:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivymd.app import MDApp
import own_classes


KV = ("""
<NewFloatLayout>
    FloatLayout:
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'icons/events/event_back_panel.png'


""")


class NewFloatLayout(FloatLayout):
    pass

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(NewFloatLayout, self).__init__(**kwargs)


class TestApp(MDApp):

    def build(self):
        self.theme_cls.theme_style = 'Light'
        self.theme_cls.primary_palette = 'BlueGray'
        Builder.load_file("test.kv")
        Builder.load_string(KV)

    def on_start(self):
      events_filling()

def pass_funk():
    pass


# заполняет экран эвентов
def events_filling():
    app = App.get_running_app()
    events_dict = [{'date': '2023-02-25', 'date_time': '2023-02-25 05:20:00', 'description': 'pat cat', 'status':
        'active', 'time': '05:20:00', 'title': 'pat', 'event_key': '-NP3v5nCWQO-VsastQdA'},
{'date': '2023-03-18', 'date_time': '2023-03-18 00:29:00', 'description': 'drink beer', 'status': 'active', 'time':
    '00:29:00', 'title': 'drink beer', 'event_key': '-NQig0z4yKmHs0o2bSe-'},
{'date': '2023-04-23', 'date_time': '2023-04-23 15:20:00', 'description': 'eat meat', 'status': 'active', 'time':
    '15:20:00', 'title': 'eat meat', 'event_key': '-NP6a-RDO0nKwH794j_F'}]
    for i in events_dict:
        layout_for_event = NewFloatLayout()


        events_box_layout = app.root.ids['events_layout']


        title = own_classes.LabelButton(text=i['title'], size_hint=(.7, .3),
                                        pos_hint={"top": .95, "right": .8}, color=(.72, .39, 0, 1), halign="left", valign="top",
                                        font_size=16)
        title.bind(size=title.setter('text_size'), on_release=pass_funk)

        description = own_classes.LabelButton(text=i['description'], size_hint=(.7, .4),
                            pos_hint={"top": .65, "right": .8}, halign="left", valign="top", font_size=15)

        description.bind(size=description.setter('text_size'), on_release=pass_funk)


        date = Label(text=i['date'], size_hint=(.4, .3), color=(.6, .6, .6, 1),
                     pos_hint={"top": .3, "left": .5})
        time = Label(text=i['time'], size_hint=(.4, .3), color=(.6, .6, .6, 1),
                     pos_hint={"top": .3, "right": .8})

        copy_button = own_classes.ImageButton(source="icons/events/copy.png", size_hint=(.25, .3),
                                              pos_hint={"top": .95, "right": 1})

        copy_button.bind(on_release=pass_funk)

        done_button = own_classes.ImageButton(source="icons/events/done.png", size_hint=(.25, .3),
                                              pos_hint={"top": .65, "right": 1})

        done_button.bind(on_release=pass_funk)

        delete_button = own_classes.ImageButton(source="icons/events/delete.png", size_hint=(.25, .3),
                                                pos_hint={"top": .35, "right": 1})

        delete_button.bind(on_release=pass_funk)

        layout_for_event.add_widget(title)
        layout_for_event.add_widget(description)
        layout_for_event.add_widget(date)
        layout_for_event.add_widget(time)
        layout_for_event.add_widget(copy_button)
        layout_for_event.add_widget(done_button)
        layout_for_event.add_widget(delete_button)
        events_box_layout.add_widget(layout_for_event)



TestApp().run()
```

Here is the kv file:

```
#:import test test

ScrollView:
    pos_hint: {"top": .79, "left": 1}
    size_hint: 1, .79
    GridLayout:
        id: events_layout
        name: "events_layout"
        cols: 1
        size_hint_y: None
        pos_hint: {"top": 1, "left": .8}
        height: self.minimum_height
        row_default_height: '100dp'
        row_fource_default: True
```

Comment: Is your code `events_box_layout.add_widget(layout_for_event)` inside the loop?

Comment: Yes, and all other widgets are added normally, but only the last floatlayout has the background

Comment: Without being able to run your code, we cannot determine what might be going wrong. Please post a [mcve].

Comment: I added minimal reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `KV`, you are defining `NewFloatLayout` as a `FloatLayout` that contains another `FloatLayout`. If it is not your intent to have a `FloatLayout` inside another `FloatLayout`, you can simply remove the extra `FloatLayout`, like this:

```
KV = ("""
<NewFloatLayout>
    canvas.before:
        Rectangle:
            pos: self.pos
            size: self.size
            source: 'icons/events/event_back_panel.png'
""")
```

If you do intend to have one `FloatLayout` inside another `FloatLayout`, then you just need to set the `pos` of the inside `FloatLayout`, like this:

```
KV = ("""
<NewFloatLayout>
    FloatLayout:
        pos: root.pos
        canvas.before:
            Rectangle:
                pos: self.pos
                size: self.size
                source: 'icons/events/event_back_panel.png'
""")
```

Otherwise, the inside `FloatLayout` gets the default `pos` of `(0, 0)`, and all three will be at the same position. Also note that the loop that adds widgets to the `layout_for_event` is adding widgets to the outside `FloatLayout`, not the second (or inside) `FloatLayout`, so the indside `FloatLayout` is essentially unused.

Comment: It woooooorked!!! Thank you very much, I don’t know why I stuck the second floatlayout there ...